# Challenging foreign registered car insurance traffic violation

Tags: united-kingdom, car-insurance

Court procedures after driving foreign registered car with valid third party insurance by a UK resident.

Hi anybody having experience challenging a traffic violation for the above. 
We had a valid foreign third party insurance which would cover an for third party in the uk. The police officer could not see our name on the green card and concluded that because we are uk residents were not allowed to drive the foreign registerd car which was my mothers. The car was impounded but we are now register it with the dvla and with a british insurance. However we want to know if we should accept a conditional offer of 6 points and a £300 fine or challenging this in court as a valid insurance was in place.

Comment: Is your question primarily if a foreign registered car on foreign insurance is legal to be driven by UK residents?

Comment: Please consider improving your question - or deleting it if you have already resolved this. It reads more like SMS/text message than a Stack Exchange question. Thanks!